# Which Dubai car rental companies allow driving to Oman?

Tags: borders, car-rentals, dubai, uae, oman

I am planning a trip from Dubai to Musandam in Oman. I would like to drive. I asked Europcar, but they don’t allow driving outside the UAE.

It is painful to email each and every rental company to ask if they allow driving to Oman. I am hoping I can crowdsource this answer.

Which Dubai car rental companies allow driving to Oman?

**Update - I got the below answer from Autostrad:**

> We can Provide You Oman NOC which is valid for 7 days & Original
> Vehicle registration document to travel to Oman & OMAN Insurance You
> have To Buy at the Border .  You must cross the Border Only through Al
> Ain Al Mezyad Border which is approved by the authorities . But
> Government rules Are subject to change as the Border is regulated &
> Governed by the Government Official.
>
> Oman Noc 525aed inclusive of vat valid for 7 days

Upon my asking, they did not give any information on whether we can cross at the Al Dhara border, which is best for Dubai to Musandam.

Which other rental companies would you add to the list? One answer below says Avis.

Comment: This random Tripadvisor thread says Hertz allows it, but it's 2 years old: https://www.tripadvisor.com.au/ShowTopic-g294006-i2046-k13685995-Driving_UAE_Rental_Car_from_Dubai_to_Muscat-Oman.html

Comment: Thanks for the info, @lambshaanxy. I have written to both Hertz and Dollar. Let's see what they say.

Comment: Here is a useful reddit thread: https://www.reddit.com/r/dubai/comments/16se0fn/oman_cross_border_closed_to_rental_cars/?rdt=41883

Comment: They said **only** through al Ain, so I am pretty sure Al Dhara is out of the question

Answer (score 5):

[Avis allows it](https://www.avis.com/en/locations/ue/dubai/dxb), though you have to book it 72+ hours in advance by phone:

> Cross Border Rentals - Oman Only
>
> Vehicles are allowed to be driven out of United Arab Emirates to Oman
> strictly through request bookings via AVIS UAE call center with
> advance notification of 72 hours.
>
> Cross border rentals are subjective to a mileage limitation/cap of
> 250km a day and excess mileage charge of AED 1/- per kilometer
> irrespective of the open mileage terms specified under domestic rental
> and online booking terms
>
> Confirmation is subject to insurance approval and fleet availability.
> Original No Objection Certificate (NOC) and Oman Insurance have to be
> collected from the assigned AVIS UAE rental locations for verification
> at the border. AVIS UAE shall not be liable for any charges or
> compensations for cross border restrictions from authorities.
>
> Oman insurance and documentation charges
>
> B, C and E car groups
>
> - 1 to 3 days - AED 450, AED 100 for additional days
> - 1 week - AED 750, AED 100 for additional days
> - 1 month - AED 1500, AED 100 for additional days
>
> K, M, N and L groups
>
> - 1 to 3 days - AED 650, AED 125 for additional days
> - 1 week - AED 1100, AED 125 for additional days
> - 1 month - AED 2000, AED 125 for additional days

Comment: I got a similar answer from Autostrad.